# Oracle SQL invalid number format exception

Tags: java, oracle, hql

I am getting an exception while executing the following query:

```
String queryString="select CONCAT( CONCAT(invoicingCollection.settleNo, '- '),((invoicingCollection.netAmountTcy - invoicingCollection.setlAmountTcy)+( invoicingCollection.taxAmountTcy-invoicingCollection.setlTax‌AmountTcy))) from InvoicingCollection as " + "invoicingCollection where invoicingCollection.portfolio in (:portfolio)";

Query query = _em.createQuery(queryString);
query.setParameter("portfolio",portfolio);
List<String> querylist=query.getResultList();
```

The error I am getting is:

> ORA-01722: ORA-01722 invalid number

Does anybody know a possible fix for this error?

P.S. When I execute the same in SQL Developer am getting the result I want.

Comment: you also have typo error "missing semi-colon". this might not solve your current issue but should prevent compilation problems of the program.

Comment: Show the actual code that creates `queryString`, along with the complete stack trace and the value of `column6`.

Comment: Do not post additional information in comments. Please [edit] your original post and add the information there. Then delete your comments.

Comment: @JimGarrison done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ORA-01722** is Invalid number error. You've attempted to either explicitly or implicitly tried to convert a character string to a number and it is failing.

There is also a problem with your query. Oracle supports table aliases `AS` in the `SELECT` list but not in the `FROM` list.

Try this updated query:

```
String queryString="SELECT Concat(Concat(invoicingcollection.settleno, '- '), ( (invoicingcollection.netamounttcy - invoicingcollection.setlamounttcy ) + ( invoicingcollection.taxamounttcy - invoicingcollection.setltax‌amounttcy ) )) FROM   invoicingcollection invoicingCollection WHERE  invoicingcollection.portfolio IN ( :portfolio ) ";
```

Comment: thanks.. ur edit also worked, I also found another way.. I executed the query as native query and  it worked form me.